# Continuous while loop in side a task

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I am learning TPL C# when i call an infinite while loop inside a task it terminates with out any error. am i doing something wrong? below is the sample code.

```
class Work2
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        List<string> scenarios = new List<string>();
        scenarios.Add("work");
        scenarios.Add("climb");
        scenarios.Add("walk");
        scenarios.Add("run");

        List<int> id = new List<int>();
        id.Add(1);
        id.Add(2);
        id.Add(3);
        id.Add(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                workInstance(id[i], scenarios);
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }     
    }

    public void workInstance(int id, List<string> scenario)
    {
        string Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < scenario.Count(); i++)
        {
            scenario[i] = scenario[i] + " " + Guid + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < scenario.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(scenario[i]);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: If you are calling this from your Main(), then it could just be naturally terminating itself after 1 second (2 x 500ms). Note: You want to be careful with your infinite loop. It is a tightloop, and could take 100% of your CPU resources.

Comment: the above program is in work2.cs in Main i just call work2 wrk = new work(); wrk.dowork(); that is all i do. Instead of task i use normal thread i do not see this problem. As i said i am just experimenting not for an application so not really concerned about 100% cpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not waiting for the `Task`s to complete. A `Process` ends when all its foreground `Thread`s complete. If you create a `Thread` manually, by default it's created as a foreground thread, so your application won't end until all the `Thread`s you created do.

But `Task`s are (by default) running on background threads (even if you specify `LongRunning`). This means you application will end even if there are some `Task`s still running.

What you should do to fix that is to wait for all the `Task`s to finish. Something like:

```
var tasks = new Task[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        workInstance(id[i], scenarios);
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a infinite loop as you thought, check the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Work2 w = new Work2();
    w.DoWork();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that I have added, the following code **Console.ReadKey();**

I now see a scrolling window with the output being printed and its still running on my PC :)

Debug your code and you will see that the threads being called in the **workInstance** method have

```
Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground=true
```

When the main thread exits, i.e. your application exits, the .NET Framework will automatically kill any threads whose **IsBackground** property is set to **"True"**

For you reference,

- [Thread.IsBackground Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx)

"*A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process.*"

Comment: That does explain what's going on, but it would be helpful to also say how to fix it.

Comment: @svick I believe that he is learning and has initiated a infinite loop on purpose in his example and wanted help on why it was terminating. If he does not want the application to terminate then as I said he could call Console.ReadKey() or set the Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground=false in his workInstance method. If you believe that the problem is in the removal of a infinite loop then the question would have to be rephrased for that.

Comment: That's exactly what you shouldn't do. Setting `IsBackground` on a ThredPool thread is a bad practice, because it's not your thread.